# Raster vs. Raster Scatter Plot in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, raster-calculator, envi

I created two raster datasets from the same world view 2 image. One dataset is NDVI, the other is a normalized surface water index (NDSWI). I would like to create a scatter plot for a pixel by pixel comparison.

I've seen a few options for how to do this but they involve running a combination function in raster calculator which only allows for integers. I need the float data. I also have access to ENVI if there is a way to do it in that software.

Running ArcGIS 10.2 and ENVI 4.4

Comment: Ok,

Some progress made. I found that the combination function in Raster Calculator will produce datasets with float data. However, I can't find anyway to input a Raster Dataset (at least the ones I have containing non-integers) into the Scatterplot Matrix Wizard. is there another way to make a scatter plot with a Raster Dataset in ArcMap?

Comment: I also have NDVI and LST data plots and I want to run the scatter plots to calculate slope and intercept of the dry edge and soft edges. can ENVI do that for me as well?

Answer (score 2):

Answered this one myself.

What I ended up doing was exporting the Raster Datasets to tiff files, opening both images in ENVI, and running a 2D Scatter plot.